# R not using more than 4GB of memory

Tags: r, ubuntu, ram, ubuntu-12.10

I'm running 64 bit R on Ubuntu 12.10 AMD64. I recently added additional 8GB of memory to my system making it a total of 12GB. But I notice that R gives me an error whenever the memory usage (of a single R session) goes above 4GB. When I ran 6 R sessions in parallel, each consuming ~ 3 GB of memory, my over all memory usage increased up to 11 GB. But a single R session is not able to use more than 4GB!
I need to train a random forest model over a large data set and I need > 4GB with a single R session.

Update:

```
R> sessionInfo()

R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.1
```

Update 2:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 92787
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 92787
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: I have no problem with 64-bit R on Fedora AMD64.  I've had it use 30G before.  Perhaps you have process quotas?

Comment: can you post the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: @Dason added the output of sessionInfo()

Comment: Does the shell command `ulimit` show anything other than `unlimited`?

Comment: I take it that `ulimit` does not show quotas, nor are memory quotas being enforced by PAM?

Comment: What does `Sys.getenv("R_MAX_MEM_SIZE")` and `memory.limit()` return?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have process limits in place, restricting any given process to 4G.

Try `ulimit -a` and look for any non-unlimited values related to memory.

Also, examine the file `/etc/security/limits.conf` and any files in `/etc/security/limits.d/` for entries on memory limits.

In particular, these two:

```
data
as
```

See `man limits.conf` for the quotas that can be enforced by PAM.

Comment: ulimit shows 'unlimited', the file /etc/security/limits.conf is entirely commented, and there are no files in /etc/security/limits.d/

Comment: @SagarJauhari Oh, sorry, try `ulimit -a` to look for memory limits!

Comment: My mistake. Added the output above.

Comment: No, my mistake...  Thanks.  Clearly something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

In a Windows OS, by default, R installs both 32 and 64 bit versions. Although, it looks like Linux does not. If you are using an IDE like RStudio it, if installed, points to the 32-bit version. You can change this in the Rstudio settings.

Comment: See the result of `sessionInfo()` in the edited question.  And I am not sure that Ubuntu installs the 32-bit version when you install the 64-bit version.  Fedora does not.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, I modified my answer to reflect that R does not install both versions in Linux. However, I am not deleting the answer because I ran into this exact issue in on of my labs. One student was using RStudio in Windows, had both R versions installed, and ran  into RAM issues. Once we changed the RStudio configuration to R x64 it worked. Does not answer this post but still useful.